# How to Set Control and WinForm Styles using a base class?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, inheritance

I am trying to create a base class to change user interface for existing forms.
I have just started to develop the class and have the following code:

```
public class UI_1:Form
{        
    public UI_1()
    {
        FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;  
        Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;        

    }
}

public partial class Form_LoginNew : UI_1
{    
    public Form_LoginNew()
    {
    }
}
```

I will be inheriting this base class to my existing form(Form_LoginNew) as shown above. On testing this, the "FormBorderStyle" is set/updated...but the "BackColor" & "Font" aren't changed.  Why it isn't working??

Also, please let me know how to change Control Styles of (button, labels..etc) using this base class. Please, remember the forms and controls are already existing . Also, i cannot go with WPF.

Comment: Properties are initialised to their values in InitializeComponent, mostly if they're touched by the designer.  They're in the .designer.cs file for the form.  So what you're doing here is setting the default, which is overwritten in InitializeComponent as this is called after your constructor.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it.  Whatever you are doing wrong is not visible from the snippet.  My crystal ball whispers something about the missing InitializeComponent() calls but that can't be it.

Comment: @Robinson : You're Right. If i set/replace  the 'BackColor' property in the .designer.cs file....It Works. But, how to achieve this using the base class above?  There are many forms in the project and i would like to achieve this using the base class which i will inherit in the existing forms. Thanks:)

Comment: You won't be able to change the style of individual buttons with a Form base class. I'd actually suggest creating a static class with set of extension methods that you can call after the `IntializeComponent` call that can set up properties for you.

Comment: Or as a quick hack I suppose you can override the OnLoad method, call base and then set your properties.  I don't like it much though.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to include a suggestion for the second part of your question too, I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the original Forms were created, they were most probably built using the designer.

Using `BackColor` as an example, if this has been changed in the designer, this will happen in `InitializeComponent` of the derived class (after your base class constructor is called) and hence whatever you set there is effectively ignored.

You could do something like this in your base class

```
public override System.Drawing.Color BackColor
{
    get
    {
        return System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
    }   
    set
    {
        // Don't do anything here
    }
}
```

If you try this, you will find you can't change the `BackColor` in the designer for the derived form because the setter doesn't do anything.

Regarding your question

> Also, please let me know how to change Control Styles of (button, labels..etc) using this base class. Please, remember the forms and controls are already existing . Also, i cannot go with WPF.

You could create your own ControlsCollection, something like this:

```
public class MyControlCollection : Control.ControlCollection
{
    public MyControlCollection(Control owner) : base(owner)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(Control value)
    {
        // Modify whatever type of control you want to here
        if (value is Button)
        {
            // As an example, I will set the BackColor of all buttons added to the form to red
            Button b = (Button)value;
            b.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        base.Add(value);
    }
}
```

To use this in your base class, all you need to do is override the `CreateControlsInstance` method:

```
protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
{
    return new MyControlCollection(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary  for the complete solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against trying to set style using inheritance and would instead recommend a set of extension methods that can apply style for you.

When I gave this a try and made a form inheriting form `FormThatNeedsStyle`, the style I set in the constructor for `FormThatNeedsStyle` was working (even in the designer).

```
public partial class FormThatNeedsStyle : Form
{
  public FormThatNeedsStyle()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Style();
  }
}

// Extension method class to apply styles
public static class Styles
{
  public static void Style(this Form form)
  {
    form.BackColor = Color.HotPink;

    foreach (var control in form.Controls)
    {
      // Apply desired styles to controls within the form
      if (control is Button)
        (control as Button).Style();
    }
  }

  public static void Style(this Button button)
  {
    button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why against inheritance?? I tested the extension method you gave above. It works . But, i would like to know why you prefer extension methods . ThankYou:)

Comment: I'm not necessarily against inheritance. It sounded like there were problems so rather than trying to make it work with inheritance, I thought it might be easier to use a different approach. I also couldn't think of a good way to handle styling buttons and other controls via inheritance.

Comment: I like this approach. One key difference in behaviour to note is that the styling in Jeff's answer will not apply to controls added at runtime. Whether or not you want this will depend on how the forms you are working with have been designed